Can TrackMania puzzles be abstracted into conrete, interesting puzzles?
I recently got back into the older TrackMania games, which have a gamemode called Puzzle. In this mode, players are given a limited amount of blocks (consisting of roads, ramps, etc.) to finish a track. A track consits of a start, a finish, and multiple checkpoints, each of which the player has to pass (in any order) before entering the finish. Your goal is to build a track with the blocks provided and then drive it as quickly as possible, getting medals based on your performance.

I want to take this concept and turn it into a puzzle which could be posted here on PSE. Obviously, the driving factor will be absent, so I had the idea of defining some basic rules with which the solvers can get their "time". You are only allowed to place tiles on cells on a NxM grid, and here are some ideas of how the current car speed could be determined: A straight road tile might increase your speed by +1, a booster by +3, a 90° turn resets your speed to 1, ramps allow you to jump and "fly over" the next X tiles, a grass tile decrease by -1, an obstacle is just an impassable cell, etc... Not sure how larger/longer turns could be incorporated (or if they even should)
In my mind this is essentially a Travelling Salesman Problem with some extra rules, i.e. that the weight of each edge is not well-defined, it depends on which path you took before (and how you took it). I am not into graph theory, so I don't know how I could even abstract this reasonably without just blowing it up by representing every possible arrangement of tiles for each checkpoint-pair, or if that might actually work out, given the selection of tiles is not too large...
Ideally, the hardcore graph-theory part of this is only relevant to the setter. The puzzle will declare the second-best possible time (the "author time", in TrackMania jargon) which the setter has to beat. If they beat it, they know it is the optimal route and post the answer. This also prevents the puzzle from allowing multiple answers competing for the best time. The question might even be tagged no-computers, which requires the puzzle to have a good difficulty level: not too easy to be solved on a glance, not so hard that you have to resort to a computer to crack it for you.

I have two questions here:

How can I, as the setter, turn a puzzle like this into a data structure on which I can then perform an algorithm on to find the optimal time with reasonably efficiency?
What can be done to make this interesting to solvers? (tile choices, etc)


A good way to restrict the space of puzzles and their solutions is to introduce bottlenecks - this allows the setter to provide a clear set of subgoals, from whose solutions the solver can complete the puzzle. There are several ways to do this:

Checkpoints: the obvious solution, but also one of the riskiest. Add too few, and the puzzle becomes completely open: Ideal for introductory or gimmicky puzzles, but hard to properly validate otherwise. Add too many, and you risk either trivializing the puzzle, or creating a Traveling Salesman problem involving optimal checkpoint order.

Speedchecks: TrackMania lingo for obstacles (usually jumps) that cannot be surpassed unless some speed threshold is met or exceeded. This imposes the subgoal "How quickly can you reach this speed, and how can you properly maintain it?"

Restrictive build environments: Fix most of the variables, and let the rest do the heavy lifting. For example, you can provide a track that is essentially complete, and ask which block placement produces the best shortcut. Or, combining with the above, forbid blocks from being placed in some region, and require the solver to build enough speed to cross the gap.


